# How to fix error The variable name has already been declared. Variable names must be unique within a query batch or stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I am creating a script in SQL Server that combines multiple queries. In each query, I am declaring a variable `@FieldName`. When I run the script it gives the below error.

> Msg 134, Level 15, State 1, Line 24 The variable name '@FieldName' has
> already been declared. Variable names must be unique within a query
> batch or stored procedure.

These queries has more code, I am just providing the minimal code.

**Script**:

```
BEGIN TRY 
    BEGIN TRANSACTION 

    Print '1'
        DECLARE @FieldName NVARCHAR(100) = 'Bank Name'; 
        

        COMMIT TRANSACTION 

        END TRY

        
BEGIN CATCH 
    PRINT 'Error' 
 
END CATCH



BEGIN TRY 
    BEGIN TRANSACTION 

    
        DECLARE @FieldName NVARCHAR(100) = 'Account Number'; 

        COMMIT TRANSACTION 

        END TRY

        
BEGIN CATCH 
    PRINT 'Error' 
 
END CATCH
```

How can we solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 possibilities. use `GO` to separate the batches. (Effectively splitting the scope of the query. All previous declared variables are not available in the next query batch.)

Or only declare the variable once and use `SET`
Most of the time you'll want option 2, to reuse the declaration. But sometimes when you have statements that require `GO` (CREATE VIEW) then you need to go with option 1.

#### Option 1

```
BEGIN TRY 
    BEGIN TRANSACTION 

    Print '1'
        DECLARE @FieldName NVARCHAR(100) = 'Bank Name'; 
        

        COMMIT TRANSACTION 

        END TRY

        
BEGIN CATCH 
    PRINT 'Error' 
 
END CATCH

GO -- Batch seperator

BEGIN TRY 
    BEGIN TRANSACTION 

    
        DECLARE @FieldName NVARCHAR(100) = 'Account Number'; 

        COMMIT TRANSACTION 

        END TRY

        
BEGIN CATCH 
    PRINT 'Error' 
 
END CATCH
```

#### Option 2

```
DECLARE @FieldName NVARCHAR(100) -- Declare once

BEGIN TRY 
    BEGIN TRANSACTION 

    Print '1'
        SET @FieldName  = 'Bank Name';  -- Use Set to set the value


        COMMIT TRANSACTION 

        END TRY


BEGIN CATCH 
    PRINT 'Error' 

END CATCH


BEGIN TRY 
    BEGIN TRANSACTION 


        SET @FieldName = 'Account Number';  -- Use Set to set the value

        COMMIT TRANSACTION 

        END TRY


BEGIN CATCH 
    PRINT 'Error' 

END CATCH
```

Comment: Ohh I was trying `GO;` not `GO`

Answer (score 0):

Unless you use GO statement, your can declare a variable once in your SQL statement

Declare that variable at the top of the statement and just change the value under each block